# Dividing one file into separate based on line numbers

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following test file:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

I want to separate it in a way that each file contains the last line of the previous file as the first line. The example would be:

```
file 1:
1
2
3
4
5
file2: 
5
6
7
8
9
file3:
9
10
11
12
13
file4:
13
14
15
16
17
file5:
17
18
19
20
```

That would make 4 files with 5 lines and 1 file with 4 lines.

As a first step, I tried to test the following commands I wrote to get only the first file which contains the first 5 lines. I can't figure out why the `awk` command in the `if` statement, instead of printing the first 5 lines, it prints the whole 20?

```
d=$(wc test)
a=$(echo $d | cut -f1 -d " ")
lines=$(echo $a/5 | bc -l)
integer=$(echo $lines | cut -f1 -d ".")
for i in $(seq 1 $integer); do
start=$(echo $i*5 | bc -l)
var=$((var+=1))
echo start $start
echo $var
if [[ $var = 1 ]]; then
    awk 'NR<=$start' test
fi
done
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried `split` ?

Comment: @123 I added an edit explaining that.

Comment: @Ed Morton Sorry for confusion. My original goal was sthg else (now explained in the edited version) but I wanted to only ask about the bug in my code so I wrote the question differently. Now, I hope it's more clear.

Comment: FYI to get the number of lines in a file, instead of `d=$(wc test); a=$(echo $d | cut -f1 -d " ")` you can just do `a=$(wc < test)`. Also, it's extremely important for you to learn to always quote your shell variables. Use single quotes unless you **NEED** double quotes to achieve a specific purpose and then use double quotes unless you **NEED** no quotes. Quotes are not something you choose to add when you need them, they're something you choose NOT to add when you need to not add them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ ls
$
$ seq 20 | awk 'NR%4==1{ if (out) { print > out; close(out) } out="file"++c } {print > out}'
$
$ ls
file1  file2  file3  file4  file5
```

.

```
$ cat file1
1
2
3
4
5
$ cat file2
5
6
7
8
9
$ cat file3
9
10
11
12
13
$ cat file4
13
14
15
16
17
$ cat file5
17
18
19
20
```

If you're ever tempted to use a shell loop to manipulate text again, make sure to read https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice first to understand at least some of the reasons to use awk instead. To learn awk, get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

oh. and wrt why your awk command `awk 'NR<=$start' test` didn't work - awk is not shell, it has no more access to shell variables (or vice-versa) than a C program does. To init an awk variable named `awkstart` with the value of a shell variable named `start` and then use that awk variable in your script you'd do `awk -v awkstart="$start" 'NR<=awkstart' test`. The awk variable can also be named `start` or anything else sensible - it is completely unrelated to the name of the shell variable.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use the `split` util available from your `POSIX` toolkit. It has an option to split on number of lines which you can give it as `5`

```
split -l 5 input-file
```

From the `man split` page,

```
-l, --lines=NUMBER
       put NUMBER lines/records per output file
```

Note that, `-l` is [`POSIX` compliant](http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1p/split/) also.

Comment: Nit pick: split isn't a bash thing; it's a POSIX mandated utility.

Comment: @Jens: Yup!, don't know I typed it ;)

Comment: The original question, which was basically 'Every 4 lines print 5 lines from the file' included an overlap of lines, which the split can't do.

Answer (score 0):

You could improve your code by removing the unneccesary `echo` `cut` and `bc` and do it like this

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(seq $(wc -l < test) ); do
    (( i % 4 != 1 )) && continue
    tail +$i test | head -5 > "file$(( 1+i/4 ))"
done
```

But still the awk solution is much better. Reading the file only once and taking actions based on readily available information (like the linenumber) is the way to go. In shell **you** have to count the lines, there is no way around it. `awk` will give you that (and a lot of other things) for free.

Answer (score 0):

Use `split`:

```
$ seq 20 | split -l 5
$ for fn in x*; do echo "$fn"; cat "$fn"; done
xaa
1
2
3
4
5
xab
6
7
8
9
10
xac
11
12
13
14
15
xad
16
17
18
19
20
```

Or, if you have a file:

```
$ split -l test_file
```